# Adding python module to raspbian

Tags: python

I am trying to follow the following tutorial: http://www.icrobotics.co.uk/wiki/index.php/Turning_the_Raspberry_Pi_Into_an_FM_Transmitter

I created a folder to put the module in and went to the directory with:

```
mkdir pifm
cd pifm
```

Then I downloaded and extracted the module with

```
wget http://omattos.com/pifm.tar.gz
tar xvfz pifm.tar.gz
```

and now I tried to type `sudo python` in IDLE and the terminal (I didn't know where to type it) both seemed to do nothing but okay.

Then I typed in IDLE

```
import PiFm
PiFm.play_sound("sound.wav")
```

And I get an error: PiFm is not defined

If however I type pifm.play_sound(...) I get that pifm has no attribute named play_sound.

I used latest version of raspbian, raspberry pi 1 and IDLE 3

Thank you, Most of the credit for this post goes to the user at stackoverflow MrHug, but since that was the wrong forum the thread was closed. You can see it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34291947/how-to-install-a-python-module-in-raspbian

Thanks in advance everyone

Answer (score 2):

The pwd command will show your current directory.  The ls command will show files in your current directory.

Is pifm.py in your current directory?

If not either cd to the directory containing pifm.py or cp (copy) pifm.py to your current directory.

The module should then be found by Python.

Comment: I usually ignore any posts on pifm. It is illegal and potentially causes interference. It may be "clever" but should not be encouraged.

Comment: @Milliways That's your choice.  I have seen no evidence that pifm is illegal in any or all jurisdictions.

Comment: I am the creator of this topic. I had to create this account. I extracted the module in the pifm folder I made with mkdir and then went to the directory with cd pifm (as I had stated?) This means that pifm.py is in home/pi/pifm but what does typing cd pifm in the terminal change the fact that idle gives me errors. And also to everyone commenting that this is illegal, I do not live in the US and this transmitter would go max 100m on a frequency no radio station uses. I don't see the problem.

Comment: So what is reported by ls in your working directory?

Comment: In Australia (and I believe UK and US if not all ITU signatories) ANY unlicensed broadcast on the "broadcast band" (which varies between jurisdictions) is illegal. I believe this is part of the WRC agreements. There are bands reserved for "class licensed" low power transmissions, but this wouldn't even qualify.

Comment: when I type 'ls PiFm.py' it responds 'PiFm.py' so no error message.

Comment: @Milliways It's not illegal in Canada or the U.S. unless the signal exceeds a certain strength.  You can buy consumer goods here that use normal FM broastcast frequencies.  I doubt the PiFM software is illegal anywhere.